# Posting image on Facebook timeline using Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I have an Android app that posts user's status messages to her/his timeline on Facebook (see the code fragment which posts the message below), the problem is that I cannot post any status images like an emoji. I tried sending the image as a byte array (someone suggested that in another post) to no avail, the picture is rejected and if I post the URL of the image, Facebooks inserts the URL instead of the actual image. Is there a way to have the image posted as a real picture? I'm using Facebook SDK 4.11 for Android and Android Studio 2.1. Any hint will be welcome. Thank you

Here is code:

```
postParams.putString("caption", getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)); // text to post
postParams.putString("message", msg);
postParams.putString("link", "https://www.terra7.net");

if (imgUrl != null) {

    //Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgId);
    //ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    //byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    //postParams.putByteArray("picture", data); // image to post
    postParams.putString("picture", imgUrl); // image to post
}

GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(accessToken, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        if (response.getError() != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MoodFragment.this.getContext(), response.getError().getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
public void sharePhotoToFacebook() {

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic);
        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(bitmap)
                .build();
        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();
        ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Log.e("onSuccess ", "result " + result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.e("onError ", "error " + error);
            }
        });
    }
```

For using above code you need publish_actions permission you can use below code for get permission:

```
public void getPermission() {
        List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");// - See more at: http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-share-an-image-on-facebook-in-android/#sthash.v7b5g7GA.dpuf
        loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
        loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);
        loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                sharePhotoToFacebook();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                System.out.println("onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                System.out.println("onError");
            }
        });
        // - See more at: http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-share-an-image-on-facebook-in-android/#sthash.v7b5g7GA.dpuf


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already tried that, but "publish_actions" is deprecated and no more supported in Facebook SDK 4.x. It doesn't work

Comment: I forgot to mention that the image must be posted on "me/feed" or any other related context which can let me post a text together with an image on the use'r wall